# Can we split this question into 2 separate questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [What MMOs influence Sword Art Online and Log Horizon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/what-mmos-influence-sword-art-online-and-log-horizon) asks the same question for two different series [log-horizon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log-horizon) and [sword-art-online](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-art-online).

Normally, such question should have been closed as too broad. However, it didn't get closed, and it got a bunch of answers, most of which only address the question for either of the series.

For *Log Horizon* only:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6960/1398
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/20318/1398 (low quality)
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/8797/1398 (low quality)
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14450/1398 (low quality)

For *Sword Art Online* only:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6735/1398
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/20339/1398
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/18572/1398

In general:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7039/1398 (a rather in-depth answer about both)
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6731/1398

How should we deal with this question? My idea is to split them up into separate question, and ask one of the employees to help with moving the answers over. What do you think?